# Error with lstlisting environment

Tags: miktex2.9, lstlisting

currently I have a problem with the lstlisting environment. Every time I try to include this to my LaTeX document, the compiler stuck at the point "C:/Users/xxxx/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/listings/**lstlang1.sty**". 
An empty lstlisting environment will compile.
e.g.

```
\begin{lstlisting}
\end{lstlisting}
```

At the moment where I try to put some text inside the environment like

```
\begin{lstlisting}
int i = 10;
\end{lstlisting}
```

or only a line break like

```
\begin{lstlisting}

\end{lstlisting}
```

the compiler stuck at the lstlang1.sty. I used the pdflatex compiler but also tested LuLaTeX and XeLaTeX (MikTeX 2.9). My LaTeX file based on the following template: https://github.com/jreichwald/DHBW_LaTeX_Template

The template also contains a lstlisting example and the compiling process of this example don't stuck. If I try to replace the template config.tex with my config.tex the compiling process also stuck. I think the issue is inside my config.tex but when I remove the lstlisting environments from my LaTeX documents, everything is fine.

Have anyone an idea?
Thank you!

config.tex

```
% !TEX root =  master.tex

%       LANGUAGE SETTINGS AND FONT ENCODING 
%
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}     % German language
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german=quotes]{csquotes}    % correct quotes using \enquote{}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% ------ Custom Packages
\usepackage{microtype}% verbesserter Randausgleich
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{manyfoot}

%       HYPERREF
%
\usepackage[
    hidelinks=true % keine roten Markierungen bei Links
]{hyperref}

% Zwei eigene Befehle zum Setzen von Autor und Titel. Ausserdem werden die PDF-Informationen richtig gesetzt.
\newcommand{\TitelDerArbeit}[1]{\def\DerTitelDerArbeit{#1}\hypersetup{pdftitle={#1}}}
\newcommand{\AutorDerArbeit}[1]{\def\DerAutorDerArbeit{#1}\hypersetup{pdfauthor={#1}}}
\newcommand{\Firma}[1]{\def\DerNameDerFirma{#1}}
\newcommand{\Kurs}[1]{\def\DieKursbezeichnung{#1}}
%\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

% ---- Eigene Counter -----
\newcounter{AB}
\newcounter{A}
\newcounter{AN}
\newcounter{AP}
\newcounter{AU}
\newcounter{HW}
\newcounter{I}
\newcounter{M}
\newcounter{MB}
\newcounter{NW}
\newcounter{O}
\newcounter{P}
\newcounter{PO}
\newcounter{SW}
\newcounter{T}
\newcounter{V}
\newcounter{VE}
\newcounter{W}
\newcounter{footnoteA}
%------------------------------------------
%--------------- Eigene Längen ------------
\newlength{\asdf} %definiere neue länge
\setlength{\asdf}{\textwidth} %setze neue länge auf textbreite
\addtolength{\asdf}{-6\tabcolsep} %subtrahiere -8\cdot textbreite von asdf
%----------Eigene Kommandos ---------------
\newcommand{\kategorieINIT}{
  * & Inhalt der Codierten Stelle. & Generallisierung des Inhalts. \\ \hline
}

\newcommand{\kategorie}[3]
{
  \stepcounter{#1}
  #1.\arabic{#1} & #2 & #3 \\ \hline
}
\newcommand{\teamdesc}[1]{
  \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{#1} \\ \hline
}

\newcommand*{\captionsource}[2]{%
    \caption[{#1}]{%
      #1 \hfill \hspace{\linewidth}%
      %\\\hspace{\linewidth}%
      \textbf{Quelle:} #2%
    }%
}
\newfootnote{A}

\newcommand{\footnoteA}{%
\stepcounter{footnoteA}%
\Footnotemark\thefootnoteA \FootnotetextA{}}
\renewcommand{\thefootnoteA}{\alph{footnoteA}}
%--------------------------------------------
%------- Eigene Umgebungen ------------------
\usepackage{xargs}
\newenvironment{MultiTable}[2][1=no caption,2=noLabel]{ 
\iffalse  
\setcounter{AB}{0}
  \setcounter{A}{0}
  \setcounter{AN}{0}
  \setcounter{AP}{0}
  \setcounter{AU}{0}
  \setcounter{HW}{0}
  \setcounter{I}{0}
  \setcounter{M}{0}
  \setcounter{MB}{0}
  \setcounter{NW}{0}
  \setcounter{O}{0}
  \setcounter{P}{0}
  \setcounter{PO}{0}
  \setcounter{SW}{0}
  \setcounter{T}{0}
  \setcounter{V}{0}
  \setcounter{VE}{0}
  \setcounter{W}{0}
\fi
  \begin{longtable}{|p{.07\asdf}|p{.52\asdf}|p{.41\asdf}|}
  \caption{#1} \label{#2} \\
    \hline
  Code & Wert & Generalisierung \\ \hline
}{
  \end{longtable}
}

\newenvironment{descriptionrueck}{
  \addmargin{1em}\description
}{
  \enddescription
  \endaddmargin
}

%------------------------------------------------------------

%-----------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{filecontents,pdfpages}

\usepackage{formular}

\usepackage[page,titletoc,title,toc]{appendix}


\addto\captionsngerman{%
  \renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{\sffamily Anhänge}
  \renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Anhänge}
}


% Correct superscripts 
\usepackage{fnpct}
\usepackage{enumerate}

%       CALCULATIONS
%
\usepackage{calc} % Used for extra space below footsepline
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tikz}


%       BIBLIOGRAPHY SETTINGS
%

% Uncomment the next three lines for author-year-style with footnotes (Chicago)
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[numbib]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[autopunct=false, backend=biber, sorting=nty, autocite=footnote, bibstyle=numeric, citestyle=authoryear-ibid,  eprint=false,doi=false,isbn=false]{biblatex}  %Use Author-Year-Cites with footnotes
\AdaptNoteOpt\footcite\multfootcite   %will add  separators if footcite is called multiple consecutive times 
\AdaptNoteOpt\autocite\multautocite % will add  separators if autocite is called multiple consecutive times
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\newline\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\addcomma\space\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
  urlseen = {Abruf am},
}
% Uncomment the next line for IEEE-style 
% \usepackage[backend=biber, autocite=inline, style=ieee]{biblatex}     % Use IEEE-Style (e.g. [1])

% Uncomment the next line for alphabetic style 
% \usepackage[backend=biber, autocite=inline, style=alphabetic]{biblatex}   % Use alphabetic style (e.g. [TGK12])

% Uncomment the next two lines vor Harvard-Style 
%\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}    
%\DeclareLanguageMapping{german}{german-apa}


\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{  %Change u.a. to et al. (german only!)
    andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},
}

%%% Uncomment the following lines to support hard URL breaks in bibliography 
%\apptocmd{\UrlBreaks}{\do\f\do\m}{}{}
%\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{9000}% Kleinbuchstaben
%\setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{9000}% Großbuchstaben


\setlength{\bibparsep}{\parskip}        %add some space between biblatex entries in the bibliography
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}   %Add file bibliography.bib as biblatex resource


%       FOOTNOTES 
%
% Count footnotes over chapters
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}

%   ACRONYMS
%%%
%%% WICHTIG: Installieren Sie das neueste Acronyms-Paket!!!
%%%
\makeatletter
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\@ifpackagelater{acronym}{2015/03/20}
  {%
    \renewcommand*{\aclabelfont}[1]{\textbf{\textsf{\acsfont{#1}}}}
  }%
  {%
  }%
\makeatother

%       LISTINGS
\usepackage{listings}   %Format Listings properly
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Quelltext} 
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{Quelltextverzeichnis}
\lstset{numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    captionpos=b,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small}

%       EXTRA PACKAGES
\usepackage{lipsum}    %Blindtext
\usepackage{graphicx} % use various graphics formats
\usepackage[german]{varioref}   % nicer references \vref
\usepackage{caption}    %better Captions
\usepackage{booktabs} %nicer Tabs
\usepackage[german]{cleveref} %referenz
\usepackage{array}
%\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}


%       ALGORITHMS
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\renewcommand{\listalgorithmname}{Algorithmenverzeichnis }
\floatname{algorithm}{Algorithmus}


%       FONT SELECTION: Entweder Latin Modern oder Times / Helvetica
\usepackage{lmodern} %Latin modern font
%\usepackage{mathptmx}  %Helvetica / Times New Roman fonts (2 lines)
%\usepackage[scaled=.92]{helvet} %Helvetica / Times New Roman fonts (2 lines)


%       PAGE HEADER / FOOTER
%       Warning: There are some redefinitions throughout the master.tex-file!  DON'T CHANGE THESE REDEFINITIONS!
\RequirePackage[automark,headsepline,footsepline]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\renewcommand*{\pnumfont}{\upshape\sffamily}
\renewcommand*{\headfont}{\upshape\sffamily}
\renewcommand*{\footfont}{\upshape\sffamily}
\renewcommand{\chaptermarkformat}{}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=0pt]{chapter}
\crefname{chapter}{Kapitel}{Kapitel}
\crefname{section}{Unterkapitel}{Unterkapitel}
\crefname{subsection}{Unterkapitel}{Unterkapitel}
\clearscrheadfoot

\ifoot[\rule{0pt}{\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox}DHBW Mannheim]{\rule{0pt}{\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox}DHBW Mannheim}
\ofoot[\rule{0pt}{\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox}\pagemark]{\rule{0pt}{\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox}\pagemark}

\ohead{\headmark}
```

Comment: A minimal example:
```latex
\documentclass[
 12pt,
 BCOR=5mm,
 DIV=12,
 headinclude=on,
 footinclude=off,
 parskip=half,
 bibliography=totoc,
 listof=entryprefix,
 toc=listof,
 pointlessnumbers,
    plainfootsepline]{scrreprt}
    
    \input{config}
    %\usepackage[]{listings}
    \begin{document}
        \chapter{Test}
            \begin{lstlisting}
                int i = 5;
            \end{lstlisting}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was related to a wrong order of loaded packages.

```
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{varioref} 
\usepackage{cleveref}
```

In this case the order should be like this one:

```latex
\usepackage{varioref} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{cleveref}
```

A big thanks goes to "Gast" from [goLaTeX Forum](https://golatex.de/fehler-mit-lstlisting-umgebung-miktex-2-9-6745-64-bit-t21800.html)